# Pressing Siri button on Apple TV 4K brings up a keyboard rather than listening for command

Tags: appletv, siri, siri-remote

On our older Apple TV 4K, pressing the Siri button brings up the swirling color ball as Siri listens and then immediately executes my verbal command.

On our newer refreshed Apple TV 4K model, pressing the Siri brings up the keyboard for typing. How can I reset this feature so that Siri listens to verbal commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings → Accessibility → Type to Siri, off.

[How to type to Siri on Apple TV - Apple Support](https://youtu.be/L9osBazYAbk)